# Remove required property from an object

Tags: typescript

I need to delete a `hash` required property from an object however, I either get some typescript or eslint errors. All the interface properties are required but I don't really want to use `Partial` as not all properties need to be optional.

Here's an interface of my object

```
interface UserRecord {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  hash: string;
  id: string;
}
```

**Way 1: Omit**

```
// User comes from a response
const userObj: Omit<UserRecord, 'hash'> = user;
delete userObj.hash;
```

Problem:

> Property 'hash' does not exist on type 'Omit '.

**Way 2: Exclude**

```
const userObj: Exclude<UserRecord, 'hash'> = user;
delete userObj.hash;
```

Problem:

> The operand of a 'delete' operator must be optional.

**Way 3: spread object and ignore the property**

```
const { hash, ...userWithoutHash } = user;
```

Problem:

> ESLint: 'hash' is assigned a value but never used.(@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars)

What would be a good solution to solve this without ignoring an eslint rule?

Comment: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/4880

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković which answer are you referring to specifically? I ain't trying tweaking with the rule.

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars#ignorerestsiblings

Comment: At this point I would edit the rule for an entire project which I am not trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can't define a strict interface and then using it like it's not.

Either set the hash property as partial in the first place:

```
interface UserRecord {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  id: string;
  hash?: string
}

delete user.hash // no error
```

Or use the "spread object and ignore the property" way.

If you can't ignore the eslint warning, you can define a function that explicitly removes the property (or use something more fancy, like `omit` from lodash/ramda):

```
function withoutHash (user: UserRecord): Omit<UserRecord, 'hash'> {
    return {
        name: user.name,
        id: user.id,
        age: user.age
    }
}
```

cf: [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdoCUIIPZQAmyA3gFDLIhwC2EAXMumFKAOYDcFycbDVAVxoAjaF0rBCjZqxCduACzjoF0luzIBfMmXwhmyAZiiMM2XAWIBeUt0rU6jAEQAhKAKTIA6nACeICCcAGjsePkYAFgBmEMpKJRVnAA88FODQyWdhODAaOBAnLR0YARAEMGA8EGQAd2AwBTwBMAAJZQVkAAojaFNjHHwiAEpGAHkaeoAeMygByyDkAHIEhUWAPls45CgIMAEoavItrYd+HqgAOlPY44kpQ2MLyRvb3jPHt9DtbV0qg3OvPVGs02ipkDY6g0mq12t1jEMgA)

Answer (score -1):

You can use classes to this as they works like types.
Here's the more complex sollution:

```
class Person {
  name = ''
}

class PersonWithId extends Person {
  id = ''
  // add here other propeties you want
}
```

Then you can create an object cleaner function like this:

```
function clearObject<T>(C: any, o: any, f: any = {} ): T {
  Object.keys( C ).forEach( ( key: any ) => {

      const keyType = typeof C[ key ]
      const Value = o[ key ] ?? C[ key ] 

      if (
        !!Value &&
        keyType === 'object' &&
        Object.keys( Value ).length > 0
      ) {
        // if key is another object
        if ( !Array.isArray( Value ) ) {
          f[ key ] = clearObject( C[ key ], Value )
          return f
        }

        // if key is an array
        Value.forEach( ( itens: any ) => {
          f[ key ] = clearObject( C[ key ], itens, f[ key ] )
          return f
        } )
      }
      
      // assign the value to it's key
      f[ key ] = Value
    } )
    // return the new object cleared and typed
    return f as T
}
```

This function will loop for each key of the type class and get from the object only keys that exists in your type class, then creates a new object and return it typed.
You can use it like this:

```
const person: PersonWithId = {
  name: 'John',
  id: 1
}

const cleared = clearObject<Person>(new Person(), person)
```

Note that now `cleared` variable is from type Person and if you try to get Id from it TS will show you an error.

This works for any Object you want to clear based on another type class without any TS error

I've created a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ts-clear-object-pw5gn7) working example or, if you doesn't need nested object keys validation, you can use [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/ts-clear-object-simplified-iv056l?file=/demo.tsx) simplified sollution too:

```
// define classes as types
  class PublicPerson {
    name = "";
    age = 99;
  }
  class PrivatePerson extends PublicPerson {
    id = "";
    hash = "";
  }

  // object cleaner function
  function clearObject<T>(newType: T, current: any): T {
    const cleared: any = {};
    Object.keys(newType).forEach((key) => {
      // assign the value to it's key
      // if key in current object does not exists
      // we get the value of newType
      // e.g: in current object does not have 'age' property
      // so the new assigned value gonna be '99'
      // because it's the default value for the class
      cleared[key] = current[key] ?? newType[key];
    });
    // return the new object cleared and typed
    return cleared as T;
  }

  // your object
  const person: PrivatePerson = {
    name: "Person Name",
    age: 18,

    id: "123",
    hash: "aPrivatePasswordHash"
  };

  // cleared object
  // this is usefull in backend if you want to
  // return a person's data to any client
  // you'll always return cleared public data
  const cleared = clearObject<PublicPerson>(new PublicPerson(), person);
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34222086)

Comment: you're right, I've updated my answer :D